# Docker for Windows 10 how to access host machine

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-machine, docker-for-windows

I am using docker for windows 10 for development. Before I used Docker Toolbox on windows 8. I am used to "tune" the host virtual machine in this case the `MobyLinuxVM`.

When I try to `connect` in hyper-v manager i get error `cannot connect`. When I try to `docker-machine ls` I get no docker machines. How can I possibly access the underlying machine on docker for windows 10?

Problems I want to solve are (aka why I want to connect):

- Ubuntu `apt-get` doesnt work for me (I am behind proxy) get errors like `E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/source/Sources  Cannot initiate the connection to 3128:80 (0.0.12.56). - connect (22: Invalid argument)`. On other hand Centos `yum`, `curl`,... works. `http_proxy` variables are set.
- I want to turn off `swap` on the host.

**update**
Solved problem with `apt-get` by changin configuration of `http proxy` in docker settings from `1.2.3.4:1234` to `http://1.2.3.4:1234/`.

**update 2**
Worked around the problem by modifying `/etc/init.d/automount` in host and added `swapoff -a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to access host `MobyLinuxVM` through container run with various privieleges.

First I ran container like that (note the **double slash** when mounting root filesystem. Single slash didnt work for me in `powershell`)

`$ docker run --net=host --ipc=host --uts=host --pid=host -it --security-opt=seccomp=unconfined --privileged --rm -v //:/host alpine sh`

after that when I got into container I just did
`$ chroot /host`

and then I could access all i needed. `/etc/fstab` or `swapoff -a`.